# Syntax Errors when using Scope Resolution Operator

Tags: c++, syntax, scope, operator-keyword, nested

I keep getting a syntax error

```
"error: expected ';' before "a""
```

on the line
`AVL_Tree<val_type>::node_type a;`
using the Cygwin gcc compiler under Netbeans.

in class "MyMap.h"

```
#include "AVL_Tree.h"
template <class key_type,class mapped_type>
class MyMap
{
public:
    class iterator
    {
        private:
            AVL_Tree<val_type>::node_type a;
    };
};
```

in file "AVL_Tree.h"

```
 template <class T>

 class AVL_Tree
 {
 public:
    struct AVLNode
    {
        int balanceFactor;
        T element;
        AVLNode * left;
        AVLNode * right;

        AVLNode(T key)
        {
            left = 0;
            right = 0;
            element = key;
            balanceFactor = 0;
        }
       typedef AVLNode * node_type;
    };
```

I was under the impression that I was able to access the "node_type" using the scope operator because the typedef in AVL_Tree is public.  The syntax error isn't being very helpful in telling what exactly is going on.  Any help is greatly aprreciated.

Comment: What is `val_type`? I see `key_type` and `mapped_type`.

Comment: If you've copied your code correctly and I've read it right, the typedef for `node_type` is inside `struct AVLNode`. That seems a bit odd, but if it's right then you'd need `AVL_Tree::AVLNode::node_type` (plus appropriate template noise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `typename` because `node_type` is a dependent type. Also, `node_type` is inside `AVLNode`:

```
typename AVL_Tree<val_type>::AVLNode::node_type a;
```